# React Native How to auto fetched the OTP in the textfield from the mobile sms,should support both ios and android?

Tags: react-native

React Native How to auto fetched the 
OTP in the textfield from the mobile sms,
should support both ios and android?

Comment: How do you send the SMS? Are you using firebase by any chance? Firebase has an auto verification mechanism which would feel the same as "auto fetch OTP".

Answer (score 9):

**For Android :** 
Google SMS Retriever API

https://github.com/Rajat421//react-native-sms-retriever-api#readme

**For iOS :**

> You will use props **[textContentType](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/textinput#textcontenttype)** of TextInput

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.codeOTP}
    textContentType="oneTimeCode"
/>
```

You can test before with this example :

> Tested on real device, and connect with the Apple account

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.codeOTP}
    textContentType="emailAddress"
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Native support added for react-native versions 0.66+!!

Android now has [`autoComplete="sms-otp"` prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/textinput#autocomplete-android).

```
<TextInput
    ...
    autoComplete="sms-otp" // android
    textContentType="oneTimeCode" // ios
/>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Is this still valid ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for ios till now for otp auto read functionality using react-native.

But for android you can use this library:
https://github.com/faizalshap/react-native-otp-verify#readme

Comment: cannot install the packege react-native-otp-verify,error occur after linking ,as cannot find symbol import com.faizal.OtpVerify.RNOtpVerifyPackage;