# React Native - Unable to get Android sms-otp autofill to work

Tags: android, react-native, sms, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I am using 0.66 (and also tried 0.68rc4) and am unable to get the autofill for otp to work on Android. Here is the component I have

```
<Input
  ...
  autoComplete="sms-otp"
  ...
/>
```

I tried the https://github.com/faizalshap/react-native-otp-verify library and it works, but am seeing if I can go with what RN provides if possible. The SMS is also appended with the correct app_hash, hence able to use the library above, but not with the out of box solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

For Android : Google SMS Retriever API

https://github.com/Rajat421//react-native-sms-retriever-api#readme

For iOS :

You will use props textContentType of TextInput

```
<TextInput
value={this.state.codeOTP}
textContentType="oneTimeCode"
/>
```

You can test before with this example :

Tested on real device, and connect with the Apple account

```
<TextInput
value={this.state.codeOTP}
textContentType="emailAddress"
/>
```

already answered in - [React Native How to auto fetched the OTP in the textfield from the mobile sms,should support both ios and android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393271/react-native-how-to-auto-fetched-the-otp-in-the-textfield-from-the-mobile-sms-sh)